# Relation in Mongodb Parse-server

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, entity-relationship

I have two questions on how to model a mongo database


1:
In 1: N, with mongodb, should I save the child entity's ID of the parent entity object, or the parent entity to save an Array with the child IDs?

In the Parse-Server I could not make the result return a list with the IDs in the parent table, I found the ID of the daughter easier and search the table for all the results that have the ID of the parent table

2:
I read about Many-to-many in Mongo, but in my db I did as SQL, I have a third table that stores the ID from the two tables.
That's right? Can it cause errors? Or performance problems?

Comment: Are you using parse-server ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using it.